# Django-Haystack clear_index not deleting database entries

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using django and haystack and my problem is that when I try to clear the index  it does not remove the entries from the database. As a result, if I rebuild the index the documents appear again. Is this an issue of haystack or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the search index will not remove the document from Django database.

Comment: So how can I clear the whole index and reindex? My application will periodically clear the index and rebuild it. Now that the documents are not removed i have duplicates